# Absolute Beginner, Visual Studio Terminal

Tags: javascript, macos, visual-studio-code

I would like to start JavaScript so I subscribed to a course for absolute beginners.
I have to start with my very first line in JavaScript using Virtual Studio Code:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Then go to Terminal and write

```
node start.js
```

Then it should print out the message "Hello World".

I downloaded node and installed, but it's not working.

I'm using Mac. I know it's very basic but I am just starting.  Thank you.

Comment: What is "not working"? Are you getting an error message? Is something else happening? Without any details we can't help you. Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Same comment as Herohtar, what's the error? Without knowing anything about the issue, is your terminal pointing to the directory with start.js? If you type 'pwd', is the output the folder where your file lives?

Answer (score 0):

On visual studio code, check "terminal" on the top toolbar and select "New terminal", here's a screen capture.

[image: Open terminal in VS code]

Make sure that you have node correctly installed, using `node -v` as below (your version might differ, just be sure it's 8 or higher)

[image: Node version check]